# Static files cant see flask server

Tags: nginx, flask, server, port

I am new to Nginx and I currently trying to deploy my web app on my server.
I have static files (built from react) being served by Nginx. The static files make calls to port 5000, my flask server. When testing, flask cannot receive any calls from my static files.

The (static-flask) setup runs on my local machine, so I am assuming that there is a problem with my config with Nginx.

Here is my Nginx setup (in sites-enabled):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name MY_IP_ADDRESS;

  location / {
    root MY_LOCATION_TO_STATIC_FILES;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

I am guessing that once Nginx serves the static files, the client (static files) make calls to localhost:5000, but does not refer to port 5000 on my server?

How would I serve the static files such that they can refer to the server's localhost:5000?

**Edit**

I guess I should be more specific with my project. I want to serve my static files when the user hits www.mydomain.com, and when the user interacts with the website, they make calls to a flask server running on port 5000 on my server.

I could consider serving static files from flask, but that would be highly inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Use nginx proxy:

```
location / {
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
  }
```

Comment: I have tried passing port 5000 as a proxy, but I am prompted with the error, '502 Bad Gateway' by nginx. On the other hand, when I do this, my flask server does get hit.

Comment: Yeah I can run flask normally under the development environment.

Comment: Maybe need to change `location /`. What is one of the Flask URL?

Comment: My flask endpoints go something like this, ```@app.route('/')
def land():
    return 'Flask Landing Page'

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login(): ...```. So if I were to call any of these endpoints it would go something like this http://localhost:5000/login

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    server {
         server_name www.yourdomain.com;

         location /static {
            alias /home/user/path/static;
         }

         location / {
               proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
               include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
               proxy_redirect off;
         }
     }
```

Change alias to your path project

Comment: When I hit www.yourdomain.com it just gives me an endpoint from my flask server (in particular ```@app.route('/')
def land():
    return 'Langing page' ```, and when I go on www.youdomain.com/static I get Nginx 404 error. So where would I access my static files?